# Trouble with MySQL function and exists

Tags: mysql

I have this sql query:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `user_login_fn`(username varchar(32),pass varchar(128),actual_user int) RETURNS tinyint(1)
BEGIN
declare compareResult boolean;
declare user_id int;
if (select EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username`= username and `password` = sha2(pass, 512) and `status`='A')) THEN
    SELECT id_user into user_id FROM `user` WHERE `username`= username and `password` = sha2(pass, 512) and `status`='A';
    SET compareResult = register_insert_fn(actual_user, 5, Concat("Login user with ID: ", user_id));
    return true;
else
    SELECT id_user into user_id FROM `user` WHERE `username`= username;
    SET compareResult = register_insert_fn(actual_user, 5, Concat("Failed login user with ID: ", user_id));
    return false;
END IF;
END
```

The problem is always returns TRUE, even if i pass a null parameters.
I test the Select stament like this:

```
select EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username`= 'prueba' and `password` = sha2('123', 512) and `status`='A')
```

And work fine, but in the function always return True or 1.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns either true or false because in the true branch of the `if` the code returns true, while in the `else` branch the code returns false. There are no other return values. If you would like the function to return some other values, then you need to change the implemented logic and make sure that other values are also returned.